# How to determine if WPF TextBox is dirty (when using UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus)

Tags: wpf

How can I determine when a user has updated the text in a textbox before the Binding has updated the source?

I was expecting to find an "IsDirty" property on either the TextBox or the Binding ...

My problem is that the "Cancel" button Enabled property is bound to the ViewModel's IsDirty property and is disabled until the focus moves out of the textbox.

"IsDirty" needs to be defined as ViewModel.IsDirty || TextBox.IsDirty

Comment: you seems to be using mvvm pattern, but you mentioned that you what to get some property directly from textbox control
_ViewModel.IsDirty || TextBox.IsDirty_.
Maybe you need just make UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and do all work in ViewModel?

Comment: The reason that TextBox UpdateSourceTrigger defaults to LostFocus is because partial edits when underlying types such as DateTime and int are used will throw exceptions otherwise.

Comment: An article with an incredibly complicated solution: http://sblakemore.com/blog/post/Dirty-Checking-your-Silverlight-or-WPF-data-entry-forms.aspx I am looking for 1 LOC not 500

Answer (score 1):

WPF can't support the typical IsDirty behaviour that users would expect in a high quality application.

The problem stems from the strange design of the Binder class.

Furthermore WPF architecture is kind of hard-coded to using the default Binder implementation, replacing it is a huge job and requires many "dirty tricks" to work around the endless WPF design flaws.

The easiest way I found to workaround this limitation is to move all value conversion logic to the view model and use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, and implement your own IsDirty and IsInvalid logic and flags.

This approach also plays nicely with Caliburn.Micro

Answer (score 0):

First, why is *Cancel* disabled? It should be enabled all the time. Any other behavior would be odd. The user should be able to cancel although he hasn't done anything.

Second, I would use `Commands` so that it can determine whether it can be executed or not based on the state of the viewmodel. Should be easy to implement, if the viewmodel also provide the implementation of the command.
I'd recommend to read some articles and/or tutorials about it. Google for the interface `ICommand`.

**And to answer your question.** Assuming you're using binding you could use the `INotifyPropertyChanging` interface to determine when a value is about to change. You could then store the current value in a backup field or something.

**EDIT - Regarding "let him lose data"**

Sure it's a valid strategy. Think on a *larger* input dialog e.g. 5 input controls, which must be validated before persisting the input. I'm assuming that the data is very important according to your arguments. Furthermore, you started to hack your data into the dialog. On input control 3 you decide to press 'ALT + F4'.

First, ask yourself, why did the user press the keys? IMHO he doesn't care about what's happening to his data. 
If 'ALT + F4' is just an example for being robust. Forget about it. I think absolute robustness cannot be implemented without being very expensive.

Second, regarding consistency and validity after the restart of the application, you have to throw the data away so that you don't start with an undefined state. Remember, the entity the user began to fill is not valid at this state. Neither the states respectively the values of the properties are.

So IMHO the much better strategy is to restart with a clean and defined state, so that the user is able to continue with whatever you want him to do with your application.
Why is this strategy better? Well, it's much easier to implement. And the much more important argument, the user never gets lost because of an odd state.

Comment: Cancel being disabled isn't a big problem, but it shows that there are 2 levels of "Dirty" and the UI often needs ViewModel.IsDirty || UI.IsDirty. If you only use ViewModel.IsDirty the user can lose data.

Comment: Data loss will occur: edit some text in a textbox and then press ALT+F4. The Closing event will check ViewModel.IsDirty which will be false, because the TextBox is still dirty ... and the window will close. The user just lost data!

Comment: Well you could add a MessageBox 'Are you sure you want to exit?...'. TextBox loses focus, value is transfered to ViewModel. *Tada* viewmodel is dirty. ;o) IMHO you should let him lose data in that case, because you cannot trigger a good validation workflow in that situation.

Comment: Huh? TextBox doesn't lose focus when MessageBox.Show() and "let him lose data" is never the right answer ... this could be a medical or banking application

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanging will not be called until the Binding attempts to update the source property. This will not happen until the TextBox loses focus, which it won't ever do if the user presses ALT+F4.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24910/discussion-between-jack-and-dhn)